# Use of comma before "and"

Tags: punctuation

Is the use of comma before "and" in the following sentence correct?

> Interviews are by invitation only, and conducted during the admissions review process.

Comment: Using "and" is correct, but I would follow with "are", so "Invitations ... *are* conducted during ..."

Comment: I am so sorry. I had posted a wrong question. I meant the use of punctuation before "and." I am confused as the phrase following "and" is not an independent clause.

Comment: I would say, *Interviews are by invitation only and **are** conducted during the admissions review process.* Or *Interviews, which are by invitation only, are conducted during the admissions review process.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Punctuation of compound predicate where the first item ends in a list?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/451818/punctuation-of-compound-predicate-where-the-first-item-ends-in-a-list) The more general question 'Should/may there be a comma before the _and_ when using a compound predicate?' is addressed. Bottom line: Here, the comma is totally optional except to prescriptivists (who would recommend against it, or worse). . How do you want it read? [However, I far prefer the inclusion of the second 'are' here.]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. It sounds better as:
"Interviews are by invitation only and conducted during the admissions review process."

Comment: Is this a case of coordinating conjunction and compound predicate as opposed to a subordinating conjunction?